# Why are zips still used even when kernels compress files by default?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, compression

Why aren't `.zip`s obsolete, now that most, if not all, modern kernels support on-the-fly compression?

Comment: zip has nothing to do with kernel. It's a generic compression format, although a terrible one, and it's very uncommon in Unix

Comment: @phuclv It's the same compression format that is used by `gzip`, but in an archive container.

Comment: @forest other than the Deflate algorithm being used, they have **nothing in common**. Saying that is the same as saying all the modern compression formats like rar, 7z, xz, zstd, lz4, lzip... are the same because they're all in the LZ/LZMA/LZ7x/Deflate family. Despite the same algorithm, some of them are significantly better than others

Comment: just because the linux kernel does: how would that help for sending a set of files as email attachment?

Comment: plus: "why is XYZ still in wide use, we can do better?" can almost *always* be answered by "exactly *because* XYZ is widely in use; the cost of migration to anything else by far outweighs the advantage".

Comment: @phuclv The _compression algorithm_ itself is the same even if the format is different. And yes, 7z, xz, and lzip all use the same compression algorithm too (LZMA/LZMA2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.zip` files are not only used for commpresion, many other file fomats may just be `.zip` files at heart. Many other file extensions are really just `.zip` files at heart but make it makes easier for software to read what is in them while also making it easier for files to be shared and stored. Imagine having to send a folder to someone and making sure you didn't save something inside it. I remember watching a youtube video about this, but I can't seem to find it. However if you take even a `.docx` file and rename it to a `.zip` then when you extract it i think it will make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Archive Utility says “Unable to expand `doc.zip`…〞, but `unzip doc.zip` worked just fine in the terminal.